# How to concantenate select objects to a list in bazel

Tags: bazel

I have a bazel target with attribute that must be a list.

However, I need selectively add elements to the list based on the outcome of a select.

```
glob_tests(
    # some stuff
    exclude = [
        "a.foo",
    ] + if_A([
        "x.foo",
    ]) + if_B([
        "y.foo",
    ]),
)
```

In the above code snippet, the functions if_A and if_B return select objects.

But when I run this as is, I get an error stating that a sequence object was expected but a select object was encountered instead.

How can I convert the select objects to sequence objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume `glob_test` is a macro that calls the builtin function `glob`.) globs are evaluated when a `BUILD` file is loaded, which is before any configuration is known. This means `glob` cannot take any `select` objects as inputs because the knowledge to turn `select` objects into lists is not present.

The way to solve this is to lift the `select` calls above the globs like this

```
some_test(
   name = "some_test",
   srcs = select({
       "//cond1": glob(["t*", "s*"], exclude=["thing"]),
       "//cond2": glob(["t*", "s*"], exclude=["something else"]),
   }),
)
```

instead of

```
some_test(
   name = "some_test",
   srcs = glob(
       ["t*", "s*"],
       exclude=select({
           "//cond1": ["thing"],
           "//cond2": ["something else"],
       }),
   ),
)
```